# Install Gtk+ on pythonanywhere

Tags: gtk, pythonanywhere, weasyprint

I am generating a pdf using weasyprint on pythonanywhere(in django). Weasyprint is successfully installed but it needs other graphic rendering tools to be installed separately. How can I install Gtk+ on pyhtonanywhere?

**EDIT**: The fonts don't seem to load unless I have Pango. Since I can't have Gtk+ on pythonanywhere, is there anyway to load fonts in weasyprint without having Gtk+ libraries?

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here: You can't install Gtk+ on our site because there's no UI for it to render to, but I think weasyprint should be able to work without it...?

Comment: Weasyprint is working but there is some problem with the fonts. It can't load fonts. Neither the google fonts nor the simple fonts. And showing multiple errors like "Expected a media type, got (min-width:992px)
Invalid media type " (min-width:992px)" the whole @media rule was ignored at 6:152543." I think its because of the absence of gtk+.

Comment: Another PythonAnywhere developer here. We will see if we can include libraries that weasyprint uses for rendering, but it will happen only when we create a new system image for our users later this year. There is no quick solution to that problem.